# Is there an Ropsten ethereum testnet API

Tags: ethereum

If we don't want to sync the full Ropsten testnet to get the current blockchain info and using the web3 api.

Is there an online full node that provide the testnet API ?

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know **only** the [Ethereum Developer APIs](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/apis) supports the ropsten network